# remove the result of removing dulplicated lines

Tags: notepad++

I m using notepad ++ and my problem is:
I'm trying to remove all duplicated lines from a text file, but I do not want to sort one of the duplicated lines,I want to remove all for example:
I have this string:

```
WWW.Google.com
WWW.Google.com
WWW.big.com
```

I want the result to be like this :

```
WWW.big.com
```

not like this :

```
WWW.Google.com
WWW.big.com
```

I have tried the duplicated lines remover on notepad++ but it also let 1 line on the result

Comment: Not a Notepad++ solution (and not sure what this has to do with PHP) but if you have Excel, you can paste your lines in there, have Excel highlight duplicates, filter on colored items, delete them all, you'll be left with all of the non-duplicate entries.

Comment: Could you maybe share the code which leads to your result? That would really help helping you :)

Comment: YES SIT good idea but when i highlight the buplicated it show me like that

http://prntscr.com/azrl5e

Comment: Yeah, so at that point FILTER the column on the color, and delete all of the colored entries. What should be left is things that were NOT duplicated.

Comment: yes i have find the  solution using excel as you said sir ,
thank you very much

i used the color method of filter 

t10x  dear

Answer (score 1):

If the file **is sorted**, then you can do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `(.*?\R)(\1)+`
- **Replace With:**  (leave empty)
- check **regular expression**
- click Replace All

**Explanation:**

- the regular expression matches a line (`.*?\R`) that is followed by one or more duplicates (`\1)+`
- the first line is captured into `\1`
- it is essential, that the file is sorted, so that all duplicates are behind each other

Comment: thank you sir but when i do this on notepad ++ it will delelt all lines whatever not duplicated

Comment: @waldiz I tested it with several duplicated lines and one unique line. The unique line remained, all duplicates were removed.   
Did you check `regular expression in the lower left and entered `(.*?\R)(\1)+` in the find what field? Are you sure that you have at least one unique line?

Comment: yes sir , i have tried and still not work on np++

look hen i check them it sellect all lines , 

look hear :

http://prntscr.com/azxlj0

Comment: @waldiz except from the trailing single quote, I cannot see what going on. Can you activate View->Show Symbol->Show all whitespace and create another screenshot? My version of notepad++ is 6.8.6, what is your version?

Comment: @waldiz http://stackoverflow.com/a/37014968/4086774 is a similar case with a more complex pattern. There not the whole line counted as duplicate, only the first part. But the idea `(something\R)(\1)+` is the same.

Comment: i have tried this regex sir buy its remove all lines expect 1 line

and mei want delete all duplicated lines  all

to nothing left

Comment: @walidz I tested my regexp with the given example in the question and Notepad++ 6.8.6 and it worked. Are you using an older version of Notepad++? I am running out of ideas, sorry.