# Regex to remove similar words by pattern

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list like this in Notepad++

```
V - Visitors  2009 - S01e11-12.torrent
V - Visitors (2009) S02e04.torrent
V - Visitors (2009) S01e01-12.torrent
V S02e02.torrent
V S02e05.torrent
Valentina S01e01-13.torrent
Valeria Medico Legale S01-02e01-16.torrent
Veep - Season 1 BDMux.torrent
Veep - Season 2 BDMux.torrent
Veep - Season 3.torrent
Veep - Season 4.torrent
Vegas S01e01-21.torrent
Velvet S01e13.torrent
Velvet S01e15.torrent
Vikings.S03E03.torrent
Vikings.S03E04.torrent
Vikings.S03E05.torrent
Velvet_S03e02.torrent
Velvet_S03e03.torrent
Velvet_S03e04.torrent
```

I want a regex to delete repeated first-second words lines (veep - veep) to have a final list like this

```
V - Visitors  2009 - S01e11-12.torrent
V S02e02.torrent
Valentina S01e01-13.torrent
Valeria Medico Legale S01-02e01-16.torrent
Veep - Season 1 BDMux.torrent
Vegas S01e01-21.torrent
Velvet S01e13.torrent
```

So if I have

```
Veep - Season 1 BDMux.torrent
Veep - Season 2 BDMux.torrent
```

I want only first line

```
Veep - Season 1 BDMux.torrent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `^([^ _.-]+[ _.-]+([^ _.-]++)?)(.*?\R)(\1.*?\R)+`
- **Replace With:** `\1\3`
- check **regular expression**
- click Replace or Replace All

**Explanation**

- precondition is that the **file is sorted**
- the first part `^([^ _.-]+[ _.-]+([^ _.-]++)?)` deals with getting the first word on a line followed by the separator " ", "_", "." or "-".

  - the first word is everything not a separator
  - the second word (`([^ _.-]++)?`) is optional to accomodate for the velvet 
    example
  - due to the use of parenthesis the first word, the separator and optional second word are captured into `\1` and what follows up to and including the linebreak is cptured into `\3` for later reuse
- the `(.*?\R)` captures everything up to the linebreak (`\R`
- the last parrt `(\1.*?\R)+` matches all following lines that begin with whatever is captured in `\1`
- the match spans all the lines, they are replace with `\1\3` and that only reconstructs the first line, thus deleting the following line

Comment: thanks for now but I update list because i saw that regex don't work for words like velvet_xx or Vikings.S03. Can you add also for words followed by `_`(underline) and `.` (dot) signs?

Comment: @SuperSonic I updated the three lists of separators.